# Why am I getting an expired token when login Twitter app?

Tags: twitter

I am building an application that will let users log using Twitter App. The twitter app got approved and I managed to generate The KEY / SECRET pair details, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

When I try to open the link set in my application to access that twitter app, I get to twitter and fill my creadentials. And I am redirected back as expected with a valid token.

The only problem is that, the token is expired with an expiration time set to "Mon Jan 1 0001".

[image]

NOTE:

1. The app is a backend app using GoLang, with "github.com/markbates/goth" for authentication (I only use API Key and API Key Secret and no Access token and Access Secret)
2. I am using "http://localhost:8000/v1/auth/twitter/callback" as the callback URL in Twitter app settings

Comment: That data payload does not look like a token from the Twitter authentication endpoints - they don't return data in that format. Is that from the Go library? What happens if you try to call the validate_credentials endpoint with the token issued?

Comment: @AndyPiper, yes am getting that in my Go application, and this data is what I got after being redirected from twitter tho. How may I use that endpoint?

Comment: I honestly would not know what to tell you other than the official API documentation as I’m not a Go expert, sorry! :-/

Comment: Oh, ok thanks, let me read into that, hope that will help, thank you!